# AttributeError at /sample/ : 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'no_of_ques'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am making a quiz application, for result calculation I have written logic ..If the value of answer stored in question model is equal to the answer chosen by user then , when user submits each question , score is incrementing by one, but I've failed to build this logic as am a new user to django please help.

Models.py : question along with its 4 options and the correct answer is in question model(These fields are entered by the user who creates a quiz by filling a form). Answer submitted by user is in answer model(This field is entered by user who takes quiz). score is stored in result model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class quiztitle(models.Model):

    Quiz_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Quiz_title = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    User_id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_of_ques = models.IntegerField(default=10)

 
class question(models.Model):

    Qid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    User_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(quiztitle,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Qques = models.TextField()
    Qoption1 = models.TextField()
    Qoption2 = models.TextField()
    Qoption3 = models.TextField()
    Qoption4 = models.TextField()
    QAnswer = models.TextField()


class answer(models.Model):

    Ansid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Qid = models.ForeignKey(question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(quiztitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    User_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Answer = models.TextField()


class result(models.Model):
    result = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(quiztitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    User_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.FloatField()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

here's views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import question ,quiztitle ,answer ,result
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import CreateUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import  authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .decorators import unauthenticated_user,allowed_users
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

def home_page(request):
    return render(request,'Home.html')
def forbidden(request):
    return render(request,'error403.html')

@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Student')
            user.groups.add(group)
            messages.success(request, 'account has been created successfully for username' + username)
            return redirect('login')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'register.html',context)

@unauthenticated_user
def handle_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            if request.user.groups.filter(name="Teacher"):
                return redirect('quizmaker')
            else:
                return redirect('student')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Incorrect Username or Password')
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')#redirect to login page



@login_required(login_url='home')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['Teacher','Head'])
def handle_quiz(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        # get post parameters
        Quiz_title = request.POST.get('Quiz_title')
        Quiz_id = request.POST.get('Quiz_id')
        no_of_ques = request.POST.get('no_of_ques')
        Qid = request.POST.get('Qid')
        Qques = request.POST.get('Qques')
        Qoption1 = request.POST.get('Qoption1')
        Qoption2 = request.POST.get('Qoption2')
        Qoption3 = request.POST.get('Qoption3')
        Qoption4 = request.POST.get('Qoption4')
        QAnswer = request.POST.get('QAnswer')
        title = quiztitle(Quiz_title=Quiz_title,Quiz_id=Quiz_id,no_of_ques=no_of_ques)
        title.User_id=request.user
        title.save()
        detail = question(Qid=Qid,Qques=Qques,Qoption1=Qoption1,Qoption2=Qoption2,Qoption3=Qoption3,Qoption4=Qoption4,QAnswer=QAnswer)
        detail.User_id=request.user
        detail.Quiz_id = title
        detail.save()
        messages.success(request,'Your question has been added succesfully')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/quizmaker')
    return render(request,"createquiz.html")


@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['Student'])
def handle_response(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        myuser = User.objects.all()
        title = quiztitle.objects.all()
        data = question.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            Answer=request.POST.get('Answer')
            response = answer(Answer=Answer)
            response.User_id = request.user
            response.Quiz_id = request.quiztitle
            response.Qid = request.question
            Answer.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/student')


    return render(request,"student.html",context={"messages": data ,"topic": title ,"user1": myuser})



def handle_result(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    quiz = quiztitle.objects.all()
    ques = question.objects.all()
    ans = answer.objects.all()
    score = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        while(score<=quiz.no_of_ques):
            if (ques.objects.QAnswer == ans.objects.Answer):
                score += 1
                print(score)
        sc = request.POST('score')
        res = result(sc=score)
        res.User_id = request.user
        res.Quiz_id = request.quiztitle
        result.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/sample')
return render(request, "sample.html", context = {"ques":ques , "ans":ans})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `handle_result` function, you have:

```py
quiz = quiztitle.objects.all()
# ...
while(score<=quiz.no_of_ques):
```

The issue here is that:

- The `quiz` variable is not ONE quiz, it's ALL of them. So it's not an instance, it's a list of instances (technically, a `QuerySet` of instances)
- Therefore, you cannot call `quiz.no_of_ques`, because `quiz` is not an instance

That's why you're getting the `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'no_of_ques'` error. Either query one specific instance, or query them all and loop over them.

Answer (score 0):

In views.py handle_result function,

replacing

```
quiz = quiztitle.objects.all()
```

with

```
quizno = quiztitle.objects.values_list('no_of_ques', flat=True)
#....
while(score<=quizno):
```

it resolves the error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'no_of_ques'` as it queries one instance i.e no_of_ques